# Kryo serialization system, how does it ensure that same ID will be generated when registering the same class

Tags: java, kryo

I check the source code of Kryo, it seems that when registering a class, it uses auto increment ID for it, if this is the case, what will happen if the writer and reader use different registeration order,

```
# writer
kryo.register(Foo.class);
kryo.register(Bar.class);
```

```
# reader
kryo.register(Bar.class);
kryo.register(Foo.class);
```

Will the deserialization still work? If not, wouldn't this be a problem? Because there's a pretty high possibility that writer and reader are not in the same application, therefore no easy way to ensure both register classes in the same order, right? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If we use the automatically generated IDs then deserialization won't work if the order of registrations is different. It is mentioned in Kryo's [documentation](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo?tab=readme-ov-file#registration) .

> During deserialization, the registered classes must have the exact
> same IDs they had during serialization. When registered, a class is
> assigned the next available, lowest integer ID, which means the order
> classes are registered is important.

There is an option to pass an integer ID while registering the class. This way, we don't have to worry about the order.

```
kryo.register(Foo.class, 1);
kryo.register(Bar.class, 2);
```

You can also make those IDs a static final member of the class.

```
class Foo {
  public static final int KRYO_ID = 1;
}
.
.
.
kryo.register(Foo.class, Foo.KRYO_ID);
```